# How to add custom HTML before each row in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using FullCalendar 5.8 and would like to add custom HTML before each row. My current code is:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import bootstrapPlugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

ReactDOM.render(
    <FullCalendar
        themeSystem={'bootstrap'}
        plugins={[bootstrapPlugin, dayGridPlugin]}
        initialView={'dayGridMonth'}
    />,
    document.querySelector('#js-events')
);
```

Which results in:

[image: Event calendar basic]

Is there some kind of event I could use to hook into the rendering process to add some HTML code before each row as show on the image below?

Ideally I would NOT like to alter HTML, but use FullCalendar's native event system.

[image: Desired calendar]

I'd be grateful for any snippet or hint. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable method I've found is altering the HTML using the `viewDidMount` property:

```
        viewDidMount={({el}) => {
            const calendarTbody = el.querySelector(
                '.fc-scrollgrid-sync-table > tbody'
            );

            for (const row of calendarTbody.querySelectorAll('tr')) {
                row.insertAdjacentHTML(
                    'afterbegin',
                    '<td class="fc-daygrid-day">content</td>'
                );
            }
        }}
```

**Update:**

This method is flawed though. It's called only once when the calendar renders and does not occur again when the calendar is re-rendered due to a month switch for example.

I need to modify the calendar's final HTML and was disappointed to find there's no such JS event which would give me access to the `el` object of the calendar when all the rendering is done. The `eventDidMount` seems useless. Any other suggestions pls?